# How to parse xml attribute values without getattribute using dom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I may be missing something very obvious in the docs, I am trying to make a more generic parsing routine that doesn't need to know the xml tag names and attribute names only that there are a certain number of levels and certain number of attributes. 
I am trying to parse xml similar to the example below to get the values of these attributes into variables with out using there names:

```
<xtest>
    <ytest>
       <ztest idx="1" a="1" b="2" c="3" />
       <ztest idx="2" a="4" b="5" c="6" />
    </ytest>
</xtest>

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from xml.dom import minidom

TAGLVLZERO = 0
TAGLVLONE = 1

def parsemyxmlwithtxttags (xmlfile):

    #load entire xml into memory
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xmlfile)
    #set first level tag
    xtestnode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("xtest")[0]
    #set second level tag     
    ytestnode = xtestnode.getElementsByTagName("ytest")[0]
    #set third level tag     
    ztestnode = ytestnode.getElementsByTagName("ztest")

    Parms = {}
    for l in ztestnode:
        mylist = [l.getAttribute("a") , l.getAttribute("b") , l.getAttribute("c")]
        Parms [l.getAttribute("idx")] = mylist

    print Parms

 def parsemyxml (xmlfile):

    #load entire xml into memory
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xmlfile)

    xNode = xmldoc.childNodes[TAGLVLZERO]
    print xNode.toxml()
    yNode = xNode.childNodes[TAGLVLONE]
    print yNode.toxml()
    zNode = yNode.childNodes[TAGLVLONE]
    print zNode.toxml()

    #At this point how do I get the attributes out of the znode


def main():
    parsemyxml("tester.xml")
    parsemyxmlwithtxttags("tester.xml")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output of parsexml

```
<xtest>                                             
    <ytest>                                         
       <ztest a="1" b="2" c="3" idx="1"/>           
       <ztest a="4" b="5" c="6" idx="2"/>           
    </ytest>                                        
</xtest>                                            
<ytest>                                             
       <ztest a="1" b="2" c="3" idx="1"/>           
       <ztest a="4" b="5" c="6" idx="2"/>           
    </ytest>                                        
<ztest a="1" b="2" c="3" idx="1"/>
```

Output of parsxmlwithtags

```
{u'1': [u'1', u'2', u'3'], u'2': [u'4', u'5', u'6']}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are expecting as output? Is it the output in `Output of parsxmlwithtags` ? If so, can you explain exactly what that is?

Comment: I am just trying to put the contents of the xml file into a dictionary, as I did with parsxmlwithtags but a list would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In `xml.dom.minidom` , `element.childNodes` refers to the children nodes of the element, and it is a list of elements . When you do -

```
xNode = xmldoc.childNodes[TAGLVLZERO]

yNode = xNode.childNodes[TAGLVLONE]
```

You are actually directly indexing that list. In `xml.dom.minidom` , `childNodes` can contain other types of nodes like `TEXT_NODE` , `COMMENT_NODE` , etc apart from `ELEMENT_NODES` .

For your current exact xml, the indexing works, but if it changes even a little bit, your program would break.

You can get an element's attributes using `Node.attributes` , this gives you a [`NameNodeMap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#namednodemap-objects) , which has a `length` attribute and `item()` attribute, you can use `item` to get the attribute using index.

If you aim is to go 2 levels deep into the xml and get the `dict/list` as you got in first case from there. You can use the following iteration instead -

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Node
#load entire xml into memory
xmldoc = minidom.parse(xmlfile)
params = {}
for xNode in xmldoc.childNodes:
    if xNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        for yNode in xNode.childNodes:
            if yNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                for zNode in yNode.childNodes:
                    if zNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                        mylist = []
                        attrs = zNode.attributes
                        for i in range(attrs.length):
                            if attrs.item(i).name != 'idx':
                                mylist.append(attrs.item(i).value)
                        params [zNode.getAttribute("idx")] = mylist
```

Use the above code in your function.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> s = """<xtest>
...     <ytest>
...        <ztest idx="1" a="1" b="2" c="3" />
...        <ztest idx="2" a="4" b="5" c="6" />
...     </ytest>
... </xtest>"""
>>> xmldoc = parseString(s)
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import Node
>>> params = {}
>>> for xNode in xmldoc.childNodes:
...     if xNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
...         for yNode in xNode.childNodes:
...             if yNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
...                 for zNode in yNode.childNodes:
...                     if zNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
...                         mylist = []
...                         attrs = zNode.attributes
...                         for i in range(attrs.length):
...                             if attrs.item(i).name != 'idx':
...                                 mylist.append(attrs.item(i).value)
...                         params [zNode.getAttribute("idx")] = mylist
...
>>> params
{'1': ['2', '3', '1'], '2': ['5', '6', '4']}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this is still using the attribute tags.  My question is: Is there a way to get the attribute values without using getAttribute, I know you can get the childNodes with out the tags but how do you get the attribute values with out the attributes,

Comment: Updated code for that, how would you get `idx` attribute without knowing its name?